# Blue prism code stage for extracting collection data

Tags: blueprism

I have collection which gets populated during execution and hence has no Fields declared. I need to extract the values of last column, and number of columns is dynamic, and am not able to do so. How can I do this with or without using code stage? (Code: VB only, as I have other code blocks running VB)

I have tried to replace the value with another variable in calculation stage like this: [my_collection.[column_name]]. It's throwing an Error when I press on Validate expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's frankly a bit overkill to use custom code stages for something this simple, especially considering the maintainability trade-off is almost always not going to be worth it in the long-run.

Using the `Utility - Collection Manipulation` VBO, you can string the following actions together to achieve your desired functionality:

1. *Action*: Get Column Names

   - Object: `Utility - Collection Manipulation`
   - Input: `My_Collection`
   - Output: `Column Names - My_Collection` (Collection)
2. *Loop Start*

   - Collection: `Column Names - My_Collection`
3. *Action*: Count Columns

   - Object: Internal -> `Collections`
   - Input: `"My_Collection"`
   - Output: `Count of Columns - My_Collection` (Number)
4. *Decision*: Is this the last Column?

   - Expression: `[Count of Columns - My_Collection] <= 1`
   - `Yes` path: #7
   - `No` path: #5
5. *Action*: Delete Column

   - Object: `Utility - Collection Manipulation`
   - Input (Input Collection): `[My_Collection]`
   - Input (Column Name): `[Column Names - My_Collection.Field Name]`
   - Output (Output Collection): `[My_Collection]`
6. *Loop End*
7. *Action*: Rename Field

   - Object: `Utility - Collection Manipulation`
   - Input (Collection In): `My_Collection`
   - Input (Field Name): `[Column Names - My_Collection.Field Name]`
   - Input (New Name): `"Result"` (or a name of your choice)
   - Output (Output Collection): `[My_Collection]`
8. *Loop Start*

   - Collection: `My_Collection`
9. *Processing Logic*

   - *Use expression `[My_Collection.Result]` to refer to the value in the current row*
10. *Loop End*

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm, but with a few changes to best suit my problem. I just had to fetch the value of last column. I followed these actions: get collection fields(step 1) -> reversed it -> renamed (step 7). And my collection is now renamed and query resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a really open ended question.

First of all a syntax like "[my_collection.[column_name]]" will not work - if you'd like to do something similar, then you may need to use action "Get value from collection by row and column".

```
Dim Proper_Row As System.Data.DataRow
Dim i As Integer = Coll_in.Columns.IndexOf(Field_name)
Dim Rows_count as Integer = Coll_in.Rows.Count

if i = -1 Then Throw new Exception ("Field does not exist")
if Rows_count < Row_number Then Throw new Exception ("Row Number higher than actual row count")

Proper_Row = Coll_in.rows(Row_number - 1)
Result = Proper_Row(Field_name) 

Proper_Row = nothing
i = nothing
Rows_Count = nothing
```

The other approach would be to rename the last column to something known. You can have an action that would return the name of n=th column and have an action that will rename the column. As a small tip - you can find a number of columns using action "count columns" from standard object called "Collections".

```
//Finding n-th column name
outname = in_coll.columns(column_index).name

//renaming column
Collection_Out = Collection_In.Copy

For Each c As DataColumn in Collection_Out.Columns
    If c.ColumnName = Field_Name Then
        c.ColumnName = New_Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The other approach could be to remove all columns except the one you want. Unfortunately, I don't have a code around that I could leave here.

And finally, maybe you could use an action that would just return a list of values from collection?

```
//Join field values to string
For Each dr As DataRow In DT.Rows

    If dr(FieldName) <> "" Then
        JoinedString = JoinedString & Separator + dr(FieldName)
    End If
Next

If JoinedString <> "" Then
    JoinedString = JoinedString.Substring(Separator.Length, JoinedString.Length - Separator.Length)
End If

OutString = JoinedString
```